# Как правильно обновить JWT токен?

Tags: php, jwt

пытаюсь обновить access_token таким образом.

```
public function getContact()
{
    // ... запрос $response

    if ($response->status() !== 200) {
        $this->refreshToken(); // Метод получает и записывает в бд новую связку access_token + refresh_token также время когда истекает access_token

        $this->getContact();
    }
}
```

Проблема тут в следующем, один из пользователей раз в 24 часа(именно столько активен access_token) получает ошибку 401.

Вопрос как правильно обновить токен, чтобы ни у какого пользователя во время обновление access_token не получилась ошибка 401.

Answer (score 0):

С токена можно получить время его жизни (первая половина токена расшифровывается), если оно прошло - заранее запросить новую пару.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]